# How java return one value when it has two value in one return

Tags: java, recursion, return-value

assume int a=12,int b=22. then how the gcd(b,a%b) or gcd(22,12) return the value?

```
private int gcd(int a, int b){
    if(b==0) {
        if(a<0){
            return -a;
        } else {
            return a;
        }
    } else {
        return gcd(b,a%b);
    }
}
```

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. This code only ever returns one value. What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: It's not else..else, it's just poor formatting.

Comment: It should return one answer. probably 2.

Comment: i did and the answer is 2 but how the formula works in this case - @ Paul Boddington  @ iCezz

Comment: @Rinku I am not sure whether you are confused about the Euclidean algorithm, or the idea of recursion in general.

Comment: @PaulBoddington pls tell me how the answer comes,,, gcd(22,12) =2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the question is here, but it sounds like you think this function is returning two values.

What's actually happening is on that last `return` statement, is that it's returning the result of the call `gcd(b, a%b);`. So it doesn't really return two values, it just returns the result of that call, which is a single value of type `int`.

Comment: it return one value which is 2 for gcd(22,12) but how the result comes 2 ? imean is there any mathematical formula ?

Comment: It comes down to `2` via a chain of recursive calls. The calls would be, in this order: `gcd(22,12), gcd(12, 10), gcd(10, 2), gcd(2, 0)`

Comment: thanks ,,,,it means 22/12 then next calls gcd(divisor,remainder) . am i right?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand the question, it's how `gcd(a , a % b)` can be used as return-value. That's pretty simple: `return gcd(a , a % b)` recursively calls `gcd` and returns the return-value of this call, which is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

How the result return 2 is basically if the value of b is not equal to 0, it will run the function gcd again in which your new a is b now and your new b is a%b. The important part is that this will be repeated in the recursive loop of function gcd until your b is equal to 0.

Once your b is equal to 0, it will go to your second loop of checking if a is lesser than 0 or any negative number. If it is a negative number, it will return the negative value of a. if it is positive or rather bigger or equal to zero, it will return the positive value of a.

If you still don't understand what I am trying to say, probably you need to understand how does gcd calculate. You can probably read more on this [website](http://java67.blogspot.sg/2012/08/java-program-to-find-gcd-of-two-numbers.html)